# c++ sort custom function

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to be able to pass in a variable by which to sort. I noticed that it only takes in the types that it will be sorting so I was wondering if it is possible to do something like that.

For example I need it to sort arrays each containing 3 integers by their 3rd int. How would you make a function like that if you did not know in advance what value you would be sorting by?

Comment: `std::sort` takes a custom comparator.

Comment: Please, read about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), about [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) requirements, then try writing some code.

Comment: I have an input I give my function which changes how everything is sorted. Is there a way to pass said input to the functioin somehow? Because I am a bit pressed for time and I am unfortunately unable to write a function for every possible sort that could be done.

Comment: You have two options: 1. Use global variable(s) to control your comparator function behavior at run-time (simple, but ugly); 2. Create [function object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) that would have adjustment options you want as part of its state, and use it instead of your function.

Comment: And please show the code you've written so far.

Comment: I need an idea if you have the time. 
if args were 1,2,3 then my program would have to sort by 1st column values BUT if two values are equal then it has to try to sort those two by the values in column 2 and so on. How would you write something like that because I just finished rewriting my code 8 times over 7 hours.

 Edit you don't really want to see the code I think.

Comment: @n0rd here is some source code 
http://pastebin.com/4RBP0Trn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said "For example I need it to sort arrays each containing 3 integers by their 3rd int," and that you won't know which index (which column) is significant until run time.

If you are able to use C++11, it can be this simple:

```
void mysort(vector<vector<int>>& v, int col)
{
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
         [col](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) -> bool
               { return a[col] < b[col]; });
}
```

If you are restricted to C++98, you can do the same thing, but instead of a lambda, you must write a functor that takes the column as a constructor parameter:

```
class ColumnSort {
    int col_;
public:
    ColumnSort(int col): col_(col) { }
    bool operator()(const vector& a, const vector& b) const {
        return a[col_] < b[col_];
    }
};

void mysort(vector< vector<int> >& v, int col)
{
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ColumnSort(col));
}
```

Finally, if you want a *multi-column* sort, the functor would look like this, where `cols` is an ordered list of columns to sort on:

```
class ColumnSort {
    vector<int> cols_;
public:
    ColumnSort(const vector<int>& cols): cols_(cols) { }
    bool operator()(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) const {
      for (int i = 0; i < cols_.size(); ++i) {
        if (a[cols_[i]] == b[cols_[i]]) continue;
        return a[cols_[i]] < b[cols_[i]];
      }
      return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is `bool operator(...)` correct?  I am used to seeing something following *operator*.

Comment: @wallyk: You're quite right. The correct signature is `bool operator()(...)`, and I've edited my code to include that fix. (Also fixed my C++11 example which was missing `<int>` from `vector<int>`.)

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. But how would you deal with col being a vector containing multiple commands? It could say sort by col 1 but if a[col] == b[col] then sort by the next thing in the vector.

Comment: @DerekJones Right now I am trying with this http://pastebin.com/MvGdEkye but it doesnt want to sort at all

Comment: @TheUnknown: Sorting by multiple columns is solved the same way, except that you would pass a series of columns to your comparator, and your comparator would need to make the cascaded checks you describe.

Comment: @TheUnknown: I took a quick look at your code in pastebin, and although the comparators look OK to me, the `sortit()` function looks fairly confused. As in my answer above, I'd suggest that you give your functors to `std::sort()` and let that algorithm do its job.

Comment: @DerekJones There are a whole bunch of cases given to us. The command to function can be. 1) A number; 2) A Number and a String; 3) A Negative number; 4) A negative number and string;
I test for all those because negative numbers cause their strings to be sorted backwards. And numbers with string "s" next to them are sorted without being converted back from string.

Comment: @DerekJones Actually is there a way to for (auto x : comm ) loop backwards? If I can do that my code will work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82345/discussion-between-derek-jones-and-theunknown).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom comparator constructed with the information about your custom sort order. You do it sort of like this.

```
// Normal sort, except the specified value always comes first
class LessThanWithPreferedValue {
    int n;
public:
    LessThanWithPreferedValue(int v) : n(v) {}

    boolean operator()( int a, int b ) const {
       if( a==n ) { return true ; }
       if( b==n ) { return false ; }
       return a<b;
    }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v = { 2, 3, 4 , 6 ,8 };

  // Normal sort, but with 4 first
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), LessThanWithPreferedValue(4) );
  // v = { 4, 2, 3, 6, 8}

  // Normal sort, but with 8 first
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), LessThanWithPreferedValue(8) );
  // v = { 8, 2, 3, 4, 6}
}
```

Comment: How would you handle the case if for example you have a vector inside of which you have the info by which to sort. I basically am sorting vectors of vectors based on the values inside of the said vectors. 

By the way this was very helpful I will be trying this now.

Answer (score 1):

Write a *functor* that takes arguments to determine how to sort. Here's a simple example that takes an argument to switch between ascending and descending order:

```
template<typename T>
class ReversibleComparator {
    bool asc;
public:
    ReversibleComparator(bool asc) : asc(asc) {}
    // This function performs the comparison,
    // returning true if a should come before b.
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) {
        if(asc) return a < b;
        else return b < a;
    }
};
```

Of course, you could have as many parameters to the constructor as you want (or multiple constructors) and make the logic as complicated as you want, though it'll be called a lot, so making it really complicated would probably not be a good idea.

An example of calling it:

```
bool asc = true;
if(argc > 1 && argv[1] == string("-d"))
    asc = false;
std::sort(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), ReversibleComparator(asc));
```

(Also, this example is a little contrived, since if what you want is to reverse the ordering, you can simply use `rbegin()` and `rend()` in place of `begin()` and `end()` respectively.)

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot of writing to do to make this work with what I am doing but I think I might be able to

Answer (score -1):

Here I describe the C rtl qsort, but it is almost certainly almost the same as the c++ variant:

The sort function takes as a parameter a "comparison function".  Each time the comparison function is called it is passed two parameters which are pointers to the two elements to compare.

After coercing the type of the parameters, you can then compare anything you want.  For example, if the elements contain some struct with an integer array and you want to compare the nth items in them where the program's first parameter tells which column, something like this will work:

```
int which_index = (int) strtol (argv[1]);

int comparefunc (void *item1, void *item2)
{
     widget *w1, *w2;
     w1 = (widget *) item1;
     w2 = (widget *) item2;

     return w1->myarray[which_index] - w2->myarray[which_index];
}


widget table[1000];
qsort (table, n, sizeof table[0], comparefunc);
```

Comment: sadly std::sort works with ranges. It is rather similar to qsort in some ways like the way that the compare functions work. The main problem for me is that. I have a set of rules that are passed in through command line and I have to have my compare function follow those.

Comment: @TheUnknown:  Any reason you can't use the C `qsort()` function then?

Comment: How would you account for the different possible inputs for sorting?
The user is allowed to input unlimited amounts of arguments.

Comment: I really don't recommend `qsort()` when writing C++ code.

Comment: @TheUnknown:  What do the arguments mean?  If they are data to sort, that is easy:  put them in the array.  If they affect the sorting algorithm, you might have to construct an expression evaluator and run that inside the compare function.

Comment: @celticminstrel:  Why not?

Comment: @wallyk The arguments are numbers which stand for columns of data to be sorted. Imagine my data as a 2d matrix. Rows are vector<string> and coluimns are string values inside vertically. So basically if my program gets an argument 1 I have to sort my vector<vector<string>> by the first value of each vector<string>. What makes this tough is that when two values in a column are equal I sort by the next passed in value through arguments.

Comment: @TheUnknown:  I have updated my answer with what I think you are asking for by using a global variable.

Comment: Why not? 1) `qsort()` is not type-safe - if you tell it your elements are 5 bytes large when they're actually 8 bytes large, it will happily go and sort bogus data. 2) `qsort()` is _slower_, partly because it's not guaranteed to actually use the quick-sort algorithm and partly because it's accessing the data through a double layer of indirection (rather than the single layer in `std::sort()`) 3) `qsort()` has no idea how large your array really is. It'll happily go and bogus data in uninitialized memory if you let it.